# Python 3.6 type hinting for a function accepting generic class type and instance type of the same generic type

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a function with the following signature:

```py
def wait_for_namespaced_objects_condition(
    obj_type: Type[NamespacedAPIObject],
    obj_condition_fun: Callable[[NamespacedAPIObject], bool],
) -> List[NamespacedAPIObject]:
...
```

Important part here are `NamespacedAPIObject` parameters. This function takes an `obj_type` as type spec, then creates an object(instance) of that type(class). Then some other objects of that type are added to a list, which is then filtered with `obj_condition_fun` and returned as a result of type `List[NamespacedAPIObject]. This works fine and also evaluates OK with` mypy`.

Now, I want to make this function generic, so that in the place of `NamespacedAPIObject` any subtype of it can be used. My attempt was to do it like this:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=NamespacedAPIObject)

def wait_for_namespaced_objects_condition(
    obj_type: Type[T],
    obj_condition_fun: Callable[[T], bool],
) -> List[T]:
```

But `Type[T]` is `TypeVar`, so it's not the way to go. The question is: what should be the type of `obj_type` parameter to make this work? I tried `Generic[T]`, which seemed the most reasonable to me, but it doesn't work. If i put there just `obj_type: T`, `mypy` evaluates this OK, but it seems to wrong to me. In my opinion this means that `obj_type` is an instance of a class that is a subtype of `NamespacedAPIObject`, while what I want to say is that "T is a class variable that represents subtype of `NamespacedAPIObject`. How to solve this?

[Edit]
To explain a little bit better (see comment below) why `Type[T]` doesn't work for me: in my case all subtype of T implement class method `objects()`, but when I try to write my code like this:

```py
obj_type.objects()
```

`mypy` returns:

```
pytest_helm_charts/utils.py:36: error: "Type[T]" has no attribute "objects"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But Type[T] is TypeVar, so it's not the way to go.

No, you are on the right track - `TypeVar` is definitely the way to go. The problem here is rather in `pykube.objects.APIObject` class being wrapped in a decorator that `mypy` cannot deal with yet. Adding type stubs for `pykube.objects` will resolve the issue. Create a directory `_typeshed/pykube` and add minimal type stubs for `pykube`:

- `_typeshed/pykube/__init__.pyi`:

  ```
  from typing import Any

  def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete
  ```
- `_typeshed/pykube/objects.pyi`:

  ```
  from typing import Any, ClassVar, Optional
  from pykube.query import Query

  def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete

  class ObjectManager:
      def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete
      def __call__(self, api: Any, namespace: Optional[Any] = None) -> Query: ...

  class APIObject:
      objects: ClassVar[ObjectManager]
      def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete

  class NamespacedAPIObject(APIObject): ...
  ```

Now running

```
$ MYPYPATH=_typeshed mypy pytest_helm_charts/
```

resolves `obj_type.objects` correctly:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=NamespacedAPIObject)


def wait_for_namespaced_objects_condition(obj_type: Type[T]) -> List[T]:
    reveal_type(obj_type.objects)
```

Output:

```
pytest_helm_charts/utils.py:29: note: Revealed type is 'pykube.objects.ObjectManager'
```

Comment: In my case, I also needed to add `__init__` stuv for `class APIObject`, so the final definition is

    class APIObject:
        objects: ClassVar[ObjectManager]
        def __init__(self, api: HTTPClient, obj: dict) -> None: ...
        def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete

Now `mypy` validates everything correctly.

Comment: `bound=NamespacedAPIObject` was the magic I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why `Type[T]` is not the way to go? The way I see it, it is quite similar to one of the  [examples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects):

> However using Type[] and a type variable with an upper bound we can do much better:

```
U = TypeVar('U', bound=User)
def new_user(user_class: Type[U]) -> U:
    ...
```

> Now when we call new_user() with a specific subclass of User a type checker will infer the correct type of the result:

```
joe = new_user(BasicUser)  # Inferred type is BasicUser
```

---

In case of using `classmethod` :

```
from typing import Callable, Type, List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Base)

class Base:
    @classmethod
    def objects(cls: Type[T]) -> List[T]:
        ...
    
    def run(self):
        ...

class Derived(Base):
    def run(self):
        ...


def foo(d: Derived) -> bool:
    return True


def wait_for_namespaced_objects_condition(
    obj_type: Type[T],
    obj_condition_fun: Callable[[T], bool],
) -> List[T]:
    a = obj_type.objects()
    return a
    
    
wait_for_namespaced_objects_condition(Derived, foo)
```

Comment: In my case, all subtypes of `T` implement class method `objects()`. Yet, when I do

`obj_type.objects()`

`mypy` complains with

`pytest_helm_charts/utils.py:36: error: "Type[T]" has no attribute "objects"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 12 source files)
`

Comment: In this case, it would be nice to see a minimal reproducible example. Nevertheless, I tried to create your case

Comment: If you want to check my exact use case, you can check it out from github here: https://github.com/giantswarm/pytest-helm-charts/tree/fixed-type-checking
Then, just run 

`mypy pytest_helm_charts`